# IllegalBlockSizeException for some users

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I have an Android app that uses Realm with encryption. We see very few cases of users getting an IllegalBlockSizeException during startup, when we setup the Realm encryption.

We create the key with the functions below:

```
private fun getOrGenerateKey() : ByteArray {
    val keyPair = getOrGenerateKeyPair()
    val prefs = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(RealmPrefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding") // We need an algorithm supported on all android API levels

    // Try reading the encrypted AES key from the preferences
    val key = prefs.getString(RealmPrefsAES, null);

    if(key == null) {
        // No key was stored, generate a new byte array, encrypt then store:
        val keyBytes = ByteArray(64)
        SecureRandom().nextBytes(keyBytes)

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.public)
        val encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(keyBytes)

        prefs.edit()
                .putString(RealmPrefsAES,  Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.URL_SAFE))
                .apply()

        return keyBytes;
    }

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyPair.private)
    return cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(key.trim(), Base64.URL_SAFE))
}

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private fun getOrGenerateKeyPair() : KeyPair {
    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
    keyStore.load(null);

    val keyEntry = keyStore.getEntry(RealmKeyAlias, null) as KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry?

    if(keyEntry != null) {
        return KeyPair(
                keyEntry.certificate.publicKey,
                keyEntry.privateKey
        )
    }

    // If we got here, there was no key and we need to generate a new one. That is done differently in the API levels:
    return if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore")

        kpg.initialize(KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                RealmKeyAlias,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT)
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                .build())

        kpg.generateKeyPair()
    } else {
        val start = Calendar.getInstance()
        val end = Calendar.getInstance()
        end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 100)

        @Suppress("DEPRECATION") // Deprecation handled by SDK version test
        val spec = KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(applicationContext)
                .setAlias(RealmKeyAlias)
                .setSubject(X500Principal("CN=$RealmKeyAlias"))
                .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                .setStartDate(start.time)
                .setEndDate(end.time)
                .build()

        val kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore")

        kpg.initialize(spec)

        kpg.generateKeyPair()
    }
}
```